# Iphone Calendar without marking etc just basic calendar

Tags: iphone, date, calendar

Could someone possibly show me how to do a basic calendar display that gets the date from date selected in a calendar? The Kal examples and code does way more than I need and is not set for the type of app im making. All I really need is a calendar with the dates, and then from there something to retrieve the date so i can pass it to my other functions. I feel like the UIDatePicker is trashy looking and would like the calendar view if its possible.

Comment: I'll paypal someone $100 if they help me get this setup and all I'm really after is a calendar on one of three tabs of a Tab Bar app that stores its date selected in a variable i can link to the app delegate. Super simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hii Casey,

For simplest / Easy Calender Integration - use Tapku Library

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Its simple than compared to Kal.

Answer (score 0):

Tapku Calendar is a solid calendar implementation, I've used it in past iPhone projects. You can check out a blog post I wrote about it earlier this year here: http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

I've recently updated it to include example code showing it's integration into a Tab Bar application. Scroll down the bottom of the post to get that Tab Bar application code. If you run into any difficulties, let me know.